# SQL keyword difference between MySQL and Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle-10g, mysql-workbench, database-design, entity-framework

Good afternoon,

Are there differences between Oracle 10g and MySQL with the CREATE, ALTER, DROP, REF, PRIMARY KEY, FOREGIN KEY and attribute variable type keywords?

The reason I ask, is I'm planning to use MySQL WorkBench to generate the SQL for Oracle 10g. If you'd recommend a different ERD modelling tool, please suggest one that can be generated from text.

Thanks for all suggestions,

Alec Taylor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are big differences between the two. The datatypes are different (e.g. Oracle doesn't have the ENGINE part, int(5) is invalid for Oracle, `LONGTEXT` is invalid for Oracle and so on) and part of the syntax as well. Oracle does not have an "autoincrement" column. It has a different concept using sequences.

If you want to find all the differences you will have to read the manuals and compare for yourself

If MySQL Workbench emits only MySQL syntax you will need some manual search & replace to convert that to valid Oracle SQL but it is certainly doable.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a lot of work, maybe I should look at a different ER Modelling tool...

Comment: I've decided to write the SQL by hand, and generate a diagram from that using SchemaSpy